# Neo4j Importing CSV File(neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: csv, neo4j

Good day. I am new to neo4j and taking time to explore things however I got stuck with loading data from csv.

I am trying to load 200k data using Load csv function with using periodic commit options but it takes time to load and pops `('neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError')`.
Please find the code which I am using to load it:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/tree.csv" as Real MERGE(P:person{name:Real.ParentNode}) MERGE(C1:person{name:Real.ChildNode})
MERGE(P)-[REL:relation_of]->(C1)
RETURN P,C1,REL
```

---

As per community blog have changed the heap size of **my db to 16G** but still no change on the output(It taking too much time to run). 
Appreciate your inputs on this to overcome the error.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check would be have you set indexes on your 'unique' properties? In this example, those would be on person.name

Information on indexes is [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/index/).

The next thing to bear aware of is eager queries. Mark Needham has done an excellent [post](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/) on this. He describes splitting out part of your LOAD CSV query to avoid out of memory challenges.